# Use Guid type in SAP PowerDesigner

Tags: postgresql, database-design, powerdesigner

I would like to use a GUID for the type of my primary key.
Do you know how to do that in SAP powerdesigner 16.5 ?

Comment: For which DBMS?

Comment: If you plan to use GUID as your primary key and create a clustered index then I recommend using NEWSEQUENTIALID() since you should NOT use the GUID column as the clustering key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally add an other data type in the tab attribute of an Entity which I called UUID and generate a UUID in SQL which is a recognized type

Comment: Thanks for answering your question.. How did you implement it? A default value, or a insert trigger?

Comment: I used UUID type and it was recognized in PostgreSQL so i didn't need to add an insert trigger i generate the UUID before inserting in the table